# how to disable lock screen wallpaper in mobile phone?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, wallpaper

I am using Gionee S6s, my phone shows lock screen wall paper default, when I unlock screen it start showing wall paper .

I want disable Lock screen wallpaper. how do I do that?

Comment: [No lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jraf.android.nolock) app may work. If your device is rooted, other possibilities exist

Comment: Not working for me